# form action and no reverse match for default auth views in django

Tags: django, django-templates

It's not really a problem, I would just like to understand what's going on:

When I override django's default template for password reset called: password_reset_confirm.html I get an error if I attempt to explicitly define form action="" parameter.

This template is called from django.contrib.auth.views

with URLs django.contrib.auth.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....

path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

]

In my template if I do:

```
action="{% url 'password_reset_complete' %}"
```

I get

```
POST /accounts/reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0 from the server.
```

If I do:

```
url 'password_reset_confirm'
```

I get NoReverseMatch.

If I remove action tag altogether it works, but I don't exactly get what's going on. So I guess my question is how to set action tag explicitly?

e: changed view to template typo

Comment: did you add the urls in main urls.py or app urls.py ?

Comment: well all urls are defined in django.contrib.auth.urls. so are "admin" templates, i just choose to override them. im not changing any of the original maschinery except the templates. I have included the whole pack in my urls.